# Java design pattern to apply a set of actions based upon event type

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a problem statement in which there are certain set of actions (A1,A2,A3,...,An). Based upon an event type (E1,E2,E3...,Em), different set of actions can be applied.

For example:

`Event E1 -> A1, A3, A5`

`Event E2 -> A2, A5, A7`

Also, more actions can be added into action set. Hence, my code should be open for extension.

I thought of applying decorator pattern, but it seems like in decorator pattern we can attach additional responsibility(actions) and return the same object.
In my case it is possible that not all actions are returning the same object and might be doing/triggering a different process.

Is there any design pattern in Java which handles this scenario?

Comment: 1. There is no such a thing as *Java Pattern*, most likely you imply *Software Design Pattern.*; 2. *I thought of applying decorator pattern* - apply to what? what is the specific problem you're trying to solve? what have you done so far?; 3. Try something yourself, and come up with a specific problem; otherwise, I think it's a bit broad and will most likely lead to the opinion-based answers.

Comment: [Observer Design Pattern](https://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/behavioral/observer-design-pattern/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Map<Event, Set<Action>>` to handle this scenario. Using the following methods:

```
void addAction(Event event, Action action) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(event, event -> new HashSet<>()).add(action);
}

void removeAction(Event event, Action action) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(event, event -> new HashSet<>()).remove(action);
}
```

you get the full control over the event and the action set bound to it.

P.S. You should override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in both Event and Action for the correct work with Map and Set. If you want actions are run in the same order they are added just replace HashSet with LinkedHashSet.